# 2 actions triggered every time I push on GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

Everytime I push something from the git bash, 2 actions are triggered. Example, on the picture below, #2 is the last time I pushed on GitHub.

Then 2 actions are generated:

- Commit (11th) <---- I named my commit like this
- pages build and deployment <----- why this action ?

On this action named `pages build and deployment` I see 'Triggered via dynamic'.

I was expecting only one action workflow everytime I push something. I have another project configured the same and I don't face that kind of problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are they really the same workflow? Could you share `on` section to se what events your workflow/s listening.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I updated my question to show `on` section. The second action named 'pages build and deployment' is something I didn't manage myself (something dynamic).

Comment: Is it a public repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-16-github-pages-using-github-actions-for-builds-and-deployments-for-public-repositories/)

> Today you will begin to see a new workflow running called pages build and deployment in your public GitHub Pages repositories. This workflow is automatically triggered when you push to the branch configured for GitHub Pages in your repository. As the name suggests, it builds and deploys your pages site. The initial benefit of this change is enabling you to see your build logs and any errors that may occur which has been a long standing issue for Pages users. However, in the future this will enable us to give you the ability to fully customize your pages build and deployment workflow to use any static site generator you want without having to push the build output to a special branch of the repository.
>
> You may notice this workflow uses some new actions actions/pages-deploy, and actions/jekyll-build-pages. For now these actions are designed to be used in the generated workflow, however, starting early next year we will introduce some additional changes that will enable you to take advantage of them.

You should be able to change this in [settings](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow)

> 1. On GitHub, navigate to your site's repository.
> 2. Under your repository name, click  Settings. If you cannot see the "Settings" tab, select the  dropdown menu, then click Settings.
> 3. Screenshot of a repository header showing the tabs. The "Settings" tab is highlighted by a dark orange outline.
> 4. In the "Code and automation" section of the sidebar, click  Pages.
> 5. Under "Build and deployment", under "Source", select GitHub Actions.
> 6. GitHub will suggest several starter workflows. If you already have a workflow to publish your site, you can skip this step. Otherwise, choose one of the options to create a GitHub Actions workflow. For more information about creating your custom workflow, see "Creating a custom GitHub Actions workflow to publish your site."
>
> GitHub Pages does not associate a specific workflow to the GitHub Pages settings. However, the GitHub Pages settings will link to the workflow run that most recently deployed your site.

But plese **Note: Publishing your GitHub Pages site with a custom GitHub Actions workflow is in beta and subject to change.**